# Laravel and dropzone.js, uploading multiple images replicate last one chosen

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, dropzone.js

I am using laravel and dropzone.js

When I upload images one by one, it works fine.

However when I select multiple images for example 3 images.

It does save the image 3 times, however it saved the last image choosen so instead of going 1, 2 and 3. It goes 3, 3 and 3.

Which is weird because it actually does 3 request therefore each image should be saved individually.

Here's my form:

```
<div class="z-index">
  <button id="modal-open" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalHorizontal">Upload Gallery</button>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModalHorizontal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="refreshPage();">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
          </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
            Drag & Drop images or click to upload
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form style="height: 50vh;" action="{{ url('/uploadgallery')}}" class="dropzone" id="gallery">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and controller:

```
public function gallery(ImgRequest $request)
{
    if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
        $s3Path = config('app.path', public_path());
        $file = Input::file('file');
        print_r($file);
        $filePath = 'public/gallery/' . time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $path = $s3Path . $filePath;
        Storage::disk('s3')->put($filePath, file_get_contents($file), 'public');
        $session = session()->get('key');
        $image = new Images;
        $image->path = $path;
        $image->entity_id = $session;
        $image->save();
        print_r($path);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally dropzone.js upload image with ajax. Can I see you js function to init the dropzone ?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line: `$filePath = 'public/gallery/' . time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();`

To

```
$filePath = 'public/gallery/' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
```

The reason is: the files are all being uploaded at the same time which using `time()` is naming all the images with same name, and when it gets on the server, of course, only one image will be available because you can't have multiple images with same name.

If actually you try 2 different files extensions, to say `.jpg` and `.png` files, with your code, they will both be uploaded.

Hope that help.